# Continuous Service Area?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst

With the [Make Service Area](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00480000000p000000) tool in ArcGIS Network Analyst, the output is a Vector layer, and the break values relate to what impedance values you pass in (e.g. 5, 10, 20 minutes or miles).

What tool(s) in ArcGIS allows me to create a [continuous](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/GISDictionary/term/continuous%20data) layer (raster) for a service area?

Comment: Give a read of this topic (http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00q900000034000000) Do you have access to any of these tools. I'd think you could just supply the output of your MSA as input to an appropriate surface tool.

Comment: Could save out the service area polygons to a feature class and use Feature to Lines to turn them into 'contours', then use [Topo to Raster](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z0000006s000000). Note that because of the way the it handles interior/exterior areas in polygon creation, depending on your network and trim distance you could get some funky results. To avoid this you might be better off only outputting lines instead of polygons, then following KHibma's method to create points out of the vertices so that when your interpolation is truly network point based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my comment - if you do:

- [Feature Vertice to Point](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000003p000000)
- [Spline](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Spline/00q900000024000000/) (The ToBreak field should act as a distance field you can use to supply the Z field in Spline)

You'll get something that close to what I think you're after.